# jQuery - When not keyPress(), keyUp() for 2 secs do function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you set the opposite of keyPress, keyup, keydown etc. Something like if the user starts to type something and then stop, after 2 seconds do function(){}

I tried onKeyPress with delay but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use keyPress and a global timer. Just reset the timer every time the user press a key.
I guess the code is something like:

```
var myTimer = undefined;
var delayTime = 2000; // should be in miliseconds.

function myfunction() {
    // do your stuff here
}

function onKeyPress(e) {
    if (myTimer) {
        clearTimeout(myTimer);
    }
    myTimer = setTimeout('myfunction();', delayTime);
}
```

PS: I have not tested this code.

Answer (score 1):

On a key event, you set a 2 second timer.  If another key event comes in before the timer goes off, you stop the timer and set a new one.  If the timer fires, then there's been 2 seconds of no typing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one oldschool way to do it is to use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`. Basically, every time a keypress happens, you cancel the previous timeout, and then set up a new one with a 2 second delay. The function call will only actually go through once someone stops pressing keys for 2 seconds, which I think is what you've asked for

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether any native way of doing this. But i have used this [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/nap) to perform this.